# Composer autoloader doesn't load class when I use variable

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader, psr-4

I've used autoloader from composer. Everything is fine when I set class name directly

```
<?php 
  namespace Matrix;
  $router = new Router;
  $object = $router->object;
  $method = $router->method;
  $id = $router->id;

  $action = new Accounts();
```

It works. But if I try to set variable as a class name

```
  $action = new $object();
```

it returns *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Accounts' not found*.

```
var_dump($action);
```

returns string 'Accounts' (length=8)

Section autoload in my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
    "Matrix\\": "matrix/controllers/"
 }
```

My directories structure:

```
├── matrix
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── Accounts.php
│   │   ├── BaseController.php
│   │   ├── OffersController.php
│   │   ├── RefreshController.php
│   │   └── Router.php
│   ├── index.php
```

Comment: you should var_dump the $object to see what it tries to instantiate

Comment: /Users/Piotr/Projects/huzari/matrix/index.php:8:string 'Accounts' (length=8)

Comment: yes the problem is that it is only the class name without the namespace. Try using Accounts::class in the Router object, or add namespace manually

Comment: @Yury Federov After adding a namespace `$object = new Matrix\$object();` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$object' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: @katona.abel It works. Thanks.